# Not hidden apostrophe in Excel cell on NPOI generated xlsx

Tags: c#, excel, csv, formula, npoi

I'm using C# and NPOI library for generating excel files. Currently I'm trying to prevent formula injection adding apostrophe in the beginning of each cell starting with =, +, -, @, etc.

The issue is that the generated xlsx file shows the apostrophe in the cell (normally if you add it directly using Excel it is hidden and you can see it only in the formula bar).
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhG87.png)

Do you have any suggestions how to achieve this hidden apostrophe?

Comment: I an excel cell there are three different properties 1) Text 2) Value 3) Value2.  I think NPOI library is using one that is not displaying the apostrophe.  See : https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/

Comment: The Microsoft OpenXML Productivity Tool (which you can get from GitHub) will let you open OpenXML files and see what's there. You can also _Diff_ two files to see what the differences are.